# Create a slideshow with 2 'controllers'

Tags: jquery, controller, jquery-selectors, slideshow

#### HTML/JS

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title><?php the_title(); ?></title>
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"              />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">                                               </script>
    <script src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();
    });

    setInterval(function(){ 
  $('#slideshow .image:first')
    .fadeOut()
    .next('.image').fadeIn()
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  2000);

    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#slideshow .image').click(function(){
         $(this)
         .fadeOut()
         .next('.image').fadeIn()
         .end('.image:last').appendTo('.image:first');
         clearInterval();
         });
    });




    
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
     <?php get_header(); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="body">

     
     <?php if (is_page('Home')){
         get_sidebar('2');
     } 
     if (is_home()){
         get_sidebar('2');
     }
     ?>  

     <div id="blankline">
     </div>
     
     <div id="why">
         <?php if (is_page('Home')){
             get_sidebar('3');
         } 
         if (is_home()){
             get_sidebar('3');
         }
         ?> 
     </div>
     <div id="information">
         <?php if (is_page('Home')){
             get_sidebar('4');
         } 
         if (is_home()){
             get_sidebar('4');
         }
         ?> 
     </div>
     </div>
    <div id="footer">
     <?php get_footer(); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

#### CSS

```
    #body {
width: 100%;
}
#around-slideshow {
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
background: #E0E0E0;
float: left;
}
#previous {
margin-top: 40px;
height: 360px;
width: 7.4%;
float: left;
background: url(images/leftArrow.png) no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
}

#slideshow { 
margin-top: 40px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
margin-left: 0;
    width: 85%; 
    height: 360px; 
    overflow: hidden;
float: left;
}
#next {
margin-top: 40px;
margin-left: 92.4%;
height: 360px;
width: 7.4%;
background: url(images/rightArrow.png) no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
}
```

This is a HTML document (with jQuery in it) and a CSS document.

I have made a slideshow with jQuery and at 2 seconds the image change to the next image.
Also i have made that if you click on a image, it will change to the next image.

But I have a problem, no I have made 2 'controllers', one for the previous image and one for the next image, but I don't know how i put that in Jquery.

Can someone help me?

Comment: It's more helpful for you to post the rendered HTML rather than the pre-rendered PHP

Comment: if you're trying to learn for yourself because it's fun, great! but there are also some existing slideshow projects. [I have one on github you could try out](https://github.com/browner12/slideshow)

Comment: I would personally create a central `Slideshow` object with `prev()` and `next()` methods (plus some others no doubt) - the code can then be kept separate and consistent, with multiple events calling `Slideshow.next()` or whatever you need, without too much extra hassle